# Prefer shorter paths for imports ESLint plugin?

Tags: eslint

Is there a plugin for ESLint that highlights longer (non-optimal) paths when the same thing is available by a shorter path?

**Example**

Given the following structure:

```
components/
  foo/
    bar.ts      # export const FooBar = ...
    index.ts    # export * from './bar'
  index.ts      # export * from './foo'
```

We can now import `FooBar` in three ways:

```
import { FooBar } from './components';
import { FooBar } from './components/foo';
import { FooBar } from './components/foo/bar';
```

where only the first one is optimal. So can ESLint help with banning the other two?